# Array of objects or strings in JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

struggling to find a definitive answer to this.

I'd writing some JSON schema validation, and wish to validate against the incoming payload being either an array of strings (that match a pattern) or an array of objects.

For instance...

```
{
    "src" : [ 
        {
            "serviceName" : "svc1",
            "filename" : "ABC000000001234567.tar"
        },
        {
            "serviceName" : "svc2",
            "filename" : "DEF000000001234567.tar"
        }
    ]  
}
```

..or...

```
{
    "src" : [
        "file://svc1/ABC000000001234567.tar",
        "file://svc2/DEF000000001234567.tar"
    ]
}
```

I have this at the moment, but it isn't working...

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "title": "My schema",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "src": {
            "type": "array",
            "additionalItems": false,
            "items": {
                "oneOf": [
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/svcUrl"
                    },
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/svcObj"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "svcUrl": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^file\\:\\/\\/",
            "required": []
        },
        "svcObj": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "serviceName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "filename": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "RequiredProperty",
                "filename",
                "serviceName"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help shed some light on this for me please?

Comment: have you confirmed the json actually contains what you think it does? Why would a client be sending you local file paths?

Comment: I'm testing it live against my own JSON in Liquid Studio :-)

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Which of the two is it accepting? neither?

Comment: I think I found it actually, just spotted the rogue "RequiredProperty" value at the bottom.

Comment: haha. yeah that'l do it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies Kevin